# Invariant of matrix under elementary transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, matrices

$\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}$
Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$, $b \in \mathbb R^n$, $c \in \mathbb R$. Consider the following matrix
$$
   B = \begin{bmatrix} A & b \\ b^T & c \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{(n+1) \times (n+1)}.
$$
Let $a \in \mathbb R^n$ be an arbitrary vector. It generates the elementary transformation matrix $T_a$:
$$
   T_a = \begin{bmatrix} I & a \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \;\;\; I = \left.\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1  \end{bmatrix}\right\} n
$$
If we denote $\widetilde B = T_a^T B T_a$ then 
$$
   \widetilde B = \begin{bmatrix} A & b+Aa \\ (b+Aa)^T & a^T A a+ 2b^T a + c \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now let $\chi_B(\lambda) = (-\lambda)^{n+1} + I_0(B)(-\lambda)^{n} + \ldots + I_n(B)$ be characteristical polynomial of matrix $B$. Since $\det T_a = 1$ we have $I_n(B)=I_n(\widetilde B)$.

**Question.** If $\det A = 0$, $\rank B \leqslant \rank A + 1$ is it possible to say that for general $a$ for some $0<k<n$ the equality $I_k(B) = I_k(\widetilde B)$ holds?

**Geometrical meaning.** Matrix $B$ corresponds to the equation of the second order algebraic hypersurface in $\mathbb R^n$:
$$
   \begin{bmatrix} x & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A & b \\ b^T & c \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = 0,
$$
that can also be written in the form $x^T Ax + 2b^T x + c = 0$. If we make a change of coordinates $x = y+a$ then we will obtain an equation 
$$
   y^T A y + 2(b+Aa)^T x + a^T A a + 2b^T a + c = 0
$$
that can be written in the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix} y & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A & b+Aa \\ (b+Aa)^T & a^T A a+ 2b^T a + c \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} y \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = 0.
$$
My question then is if some $k$, $0<k<n$, $I_k$ is an invariant of second-order algebraic hypersurface under translation transformations $x \mapsto x+a$. In general it isn't true, but under assumptions $\det A = 0$, $\rank B \leqslant \rank A + 1$ I don't know the answer.